# My django project isn't logging out, giving weird error

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a weird error when I try to log out a user on my django project:
[image]

This is my logout view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_now(request):
    logout(request)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: @ubershmekel Ya. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view needs to return a HTTP response, for example a redirect:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def logout_now(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('name-of-some-view')
```

If the user makes a request, then the server needs to send a HTTP response. This does not *per se* needs to be a redirect. You can for example return a HTTP response with a message.

Note that normally actions with side effects, like a logout, should only be done through a POST request, not a GET request. You thus perhaps should work with the [**`@require_POST`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST).